# What is the meaning of conservative dynamics in the context of Conway's Game of Life

Tags: cellular-automata

While reading up about Conway's Game of Life, I often come across the term conservative or non-conservative dynamics. What exactly does these terms mean?

My guess is that a certain quantity (e.g., number of dead cells) always remains the same as the system evolves. Is this what it means? Thank you.

The paper I was looking at is "Phase transitions in a Conservative Game of Life" by Hans J. Herrmann (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.07225.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some relevant quotes from the paper:

> We investigate the dynamics of a conservative version of Conway’s Game of Life, in which a pair consisting
> of a dead and a living cell can switch their states following Conway’s rules but only by swapping their positions,
> irrespective of their mutual distance.

> A common feature of these previous studies is that they
> preserve the nonconservative nature of the dynamical rules.
> Here, on the other hand, we modify the dynamical rules in
> order to enforce conservation of the number of cells of both
> types.

> In contrast to the original version of the Game of Life, we assume
> a conservative, asynchronous and nonlocal dynamics: at each time step, we randomly select an unsatisfied living cell and an
> unsatisfied dead cell and we switch their states

In other words, a dynamics is *conservative* if it conserves the number of cells of each type.